# Troubleshooting a Kivy GUI issue in a systemd service on Raspberry Pi

Tags: systemd, python, raspberry-pi, gui, touch-screen

I'm using a simple Kivy script for a GUI to work on a Raspberry Pi touchscreen. It works fine when running directly as `/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/kivy_script.py`. However, when my systemd service runs it, I don't get a UI.

```
Description=This file handles the enviroment info python application
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=pi
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/simple_timer/main.py
Restart=on-failure
    
    
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Does anyone have any tips for what might be wrong and what I can do to fix it?